# understanding why plugin initializations are stored in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just looking at how the [srollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) plugin works and basically the following code was used to initialize the plugin:

```
var s = skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
    });
```

ofcourse the plugin can also be initialized like so:

```
skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
    });
```

now my question here is very simple, what is the advantage of initializing a plugin and storing it in a variable? I guess this is a fundamental javascript question rather than a jQuery or plugin related question.

I know that for example if you have a function like below:

```
var x = setTimeout(function(){ // do something }, 2000);
```

now since we store the setTimeout in a variable, we can now easily use clearTimeout() to erase the setTimeout(), like so:

```
clearTimeout(x);
```

but in case of plugin initialization I fail to see the benefit, can anybody explain?

Comment: depends if they return something useful .

Comment: @A.Wolff , yes true , it would be great , if i could see an example of what could be done with the `s` after initilization :)

Comment: In case of this plugin, this variable exposes some methods that can be useful to call later, e.g: `s.destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

So that you you have a reference to the object, allowing you to manipulate it later on.

i.e.

```
var graph = Graph.init("#somewhere", data);

// later on, change graph data

graph.update(newData);
```

It may not always be necessary to manipulate the object later on, in that case you don't need to assign it to a variable.